# Sharing data between multiple view controllers with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a handful of view controllers that inherit from a subclass of UIViewController, we will call it **SpecialViewController**. The point of SpecialViewController is to store all of the redundant properties, etc that each of the other view controllers can inherit from. The lifecycle of the application goes from the first to the last view controller, collecting a few pieces of information, so that by the last view controller, there is a full entry of data to be saved to Core Data. Currently my AppDelegate is what holds my model, context, and persistent store coordinator, and I have a subclass of NSManagedObject called **Person**. My question is, what is the best way to build up the data to the last view controller, then save it?

### Can I pass an instance of my Person NSManagedObject from view controller to view controller until it's ready to be committed to the Core Data database?

If so, would it be bad design to have the designated initializer of my **SpecialViewController** be a method like:

```
-(id)initWithManagedObjectInstance:(Person *)personManagedObject
```

and then in the end I could take the completed set of "Person" data (in the last view controller) and commit it to the database...?

Feel free to argue my idea, I want to build it the best way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think that will work. The way you would normally do this, or at least the way I do it, is to pass your ManagedObjectContext from your AppDelegate to your first SpecialViewController and from there pass it to each successive SpecialViewController. Make sure SpecialViewController has a property defined as `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;` and then set it as the ManagedObjectContext of whatever class you are in: `specialViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;` for each new SpecialViewController you create. Then you can save it at the end with:

```
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving: %@", error);
        // Error handling
    }
```

EDIT: Oh wait, I see what you are saying, sorry. Yes, I think you can. lol. Haven't tried it though. I would probably do this by creating a `Person` unaffiliated with core data, passing that from view to view, and then when i needed to save it, creating one affiliated with core data with `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` and copying all of the info from the other one to the new one.

Comment: two good suggestions, I think that's the affirmation I needed. I'm going to try passing the context first, because I think that would be better if I decided to change the information that I'm using with Core Data at a later time. Thanks!